# Getting video url from image picker in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm facing a problem selecting the video url from the photo gallery. When the image picker is presented, it can not choose but I try to choose it. It automatically compressing and image picker is not dissmissed.

This is my code.

```
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self
self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as! String]

self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    var videoURL: NSURL? = nil
    videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? NSURL
    print(videoURL)

    imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: try this:     picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil),after this code video gallery is open after selecting video or choose video it automaically compressed and pickerview is not dissmissed

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift 4.2**, you must use a new enum provided by Apple to capture the video URL:

```
// Using the full key
if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
    // Do something with the URL
}

// Using just the information key value
if let url = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
    // Do something with the URL
}
```

You can read about `mediaURL` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey/1619149-mediaurl).

> Specifies the filesystem URL for the movie.

Comment: Type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'mediaURL'

Answer (score 1):

You can get video url from `info` like,

```
videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
print("videoURL:\(String(describing: videoURL))")
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Don't use `String(describing:)`, it doesn't do what you think it does. Use a normal String initializer - or even better in this case, just insert `videoURL` in the interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let mediaURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL else { return }
    // You can do whatever youo want here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple like this.

```
extension HomeVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL
        // Do something with the videoUrl

        DispatchQueue.main.async { // Dismiss it, remember using `picker`
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code for Select the video without compression :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                             didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String
    let videoString = kUTTypeVideo as? String
    let movieString = kUTTypeMovie as? String

    if (mediaType == videoString) || (mediaType == movieString) {
      var videoRef = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL
      var refResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [videoRef], options: nil) as? PHFetchResult
      var videoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
      videoRequestOptions.version() = .original
      PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: refResult.firstObject as? PHAsset ?? PHAsset(), options: videoRequestOptions, resultHandler: {(_ asset: AVAsset, _ audioMix: AVAudioMix, _ info: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void in
        if (asset is AVURLAsset) {
          var originURL: URL? = (asset as? AVURLAsset)?.url
          // Now you have the URL of the original video.
          picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
          picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: but this function is not call due to   self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)